# How to find a vertex correct as from the latlong on pgRouting 2.1.0 +?

Tags: pgrouting, vertices

Using the syntax (SQL) then the 1º result found in my table of vertices is the street segment highlighted in blue, but if I use the "limit" greater than one (eg = 3), the street segment In red is found. The correct result would be the vertex of "Rua Expedicionário Guilherme Brasileiro", where is my lat long( current location). Observe the figure.

[image]

**Using Limit = 1:**

```
SELECT ways.gid,  ways.name, ST_AsText(the_geom) as the_geom FROM ways ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-34.935373 -8.037455)',4326) LIMIT 1;
```

**Result:**

---

65824, Rua São Mateus, LINESTRING(-34.9352902 -8.0367307,-34.9355167 -8.0373642)

---

**Using Limit > 1:**

```
SELECT ways.gid,  ways.name, ST_AsText(the_geom) as the_geom FROM ways ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-34.935373 -8.037455)',4326) LIMIT 3;
```

**Result:**
[image]

Can anyone suggest me other alternatives to find this information in my vertices table in a more precise way?

Comment: These results are giving you the same information, because the first row of the result with three records is the same when you limit the result to one record (GID 65824). If you want to be explicit about your order, try `ORDER BY ... ASC` and `ORDER BY ... DESC` (ascending or descending order). I believe it will do ascending order by default, which again means that the first row in either query is the correct result (the segment that is closest to your input). My guess is just that your road segment geometries don't line up with Google, which you seem to be using for validation.

Comment: OK @RichardLaw, but you know another way to bring these same values
without using the operator <-> ? For you, this would be the most appropriate?
I used the google data to validate because latlong values are reported from an android app (which uses nativmente google map). there is some impact? Help-me  please, I am beginner in pgrouting!

Comment: My advice would be to validate your results visually with something that shows both the point and the line features, rather than the point and someone else's line features. As far as I can see, the query is giving you the correct result.

Comment: Thank you @RichardLaw !!!  May suggest some tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a [Nearest Neighbour Search](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html), but you have got it slightly wrong.

The `<->` operator does the distance between box centers.  So in this case the center of the box for "Rua São Mateus" is closer to the search point than the box center of "Rua Expedicionário Guilherme Brasileiro".  `ST_Distance` will do closest point on the line and will give you "Rua Expedicionário Guilherme Brasileiro" as closest.

This shows what the data looks like for your example
[image]

You will need to alter you search slightly to get it to accurately return the correct result.  Something like follows

```
WITH close100 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ways
    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-34.935373 -8.037455)',4326)
    LIMIT 100
)
SELECT gid, 
    name, 
    ST_AsText(the_geom) as the_geom
FROM close100 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(the_geom, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-34.935373 -8.037455)',4326))
LIMIT 1;
```

As noted by @LR1234567 and as stated in the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/geometry_distance_knn.html), the `<->` operator will return the true nearest neighbour distance when versions are PostGIS 2.2+ and PostgreSQL 9.5+.  The performance of the query above is likely to be poorer than OP's original query which would work.

Comment: This is only true if you are using PostGIS < 2.2 or PostgreSQL < 9.5. If you are running on PostGIS 2.2+ and PostgreSQL 9.5+, the <-> operator is true distance and not box, so the CTE is no longer necessary.